# Ruling on pants with fallen drops of urine

Tags: salat, fiqh, self-purification

Having OCD I usually avoid washing my area immediately after urinating otherwise it leads me feeling urges to urinate again and it's really frustrating that's why I let the area to relax for some moments and don't touch it. But the problem is when I stand up after a suspended drop left falls randomly on pants. Now I can't even wash that area because I have my pants lowered and am only left with washing the whole pant. Is there any measure I can adopt to this. Or can I be excused in this matter for not trying to prevent the drop? I don't do so because of the fear of further obsessions and they're really annoying compelling me spend a plenty of time in washroom.

Comment: Take your pants off and hang them when you go to urinate and only wear them again after washing. Or keep sitting and do not stand. Or use a toilet paper to dry the urine. Or get treatment\therapy for your OCD or do anything else which comes to mind. If urine soils clothes then that clothing becomes unclean.

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. Alhamdullilah that you are worried about your cleanliness. That is an admirable quality. Keep that up.

When it comes to your OCD I would recommend to take Omega 3 supplement and see if that helps with the obsessive compulsiveness.

Now to the part of the urine. You might have Post Micturition Dribble or just normal pee that comes out after urination. I would recommend getting a plastic bag (small size) and wrap it around your private part. Walk for a little while and then take that plastic off and wash your private part. It should be good then. You can even use a condom if you have as a way to catch any post urine drips. Moreover, trying doing some exercise to make your pelvic area stronger like pelvic floor exercises.

I believe this will help because then after lets say 5 to 10 minutes you know that drops will not come out and you can wash yourself instead of having to wash your pants from where the urine fell on.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Answer (score 1):

Al-Baqarah (2:286)

Allah does not require of any soul more than what it can afford. All good will be for its own benefit, and all evil will be to its own loss. ˹The believers pray,˺ “Our Lord! Do not punish us if we forget or make a mistake. Our Lord! Do not place a burden on us like the one you placed on those before us. Our Lord! Do not burden us with what we cannot bear. Pardon us, forgive us, and have mercy on us. You are our ˹only˺ Guardian. So grant us victory over the disbelieving people.”

— Translated by Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran

I am not an expert. But, in my opinion, don't be hard on yourself. Indeed, Allah does not task anyone beyond their capacity.